# How to store 2 values into cookie

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I am trying to store the drop down list selected values to cookie.

Here what happens is i have 2 drop down list.When i select the values from 2 drop down list and click submit button the 2 values which i have selected in drop down list should store in cookies..

How can i do this?

here is the code that i have used..

Javascript Code:

```
function CreateCookie()
{
   if( document.myform.genre.value == "" ){
      alert("Select some value!");
      return;
   }


   cookievalue1= escape(document.myform.genre.value) + ";";
   document.cookie="genre=" + cookievalue1;
   alert("Setting Cookies : " + "genre=" + cookievalue1 );

   cookievalue2= escape(document.myform.movie.value) + ";";
   document.cookie="movie=" + cookievalue2; 
   alert("Setting Cookies : " + "movie=" + cookievalue2 );


}
```

HTML code

```
<table border="0" class="preference">
<tr>
<td>
Genre:&nbsp;
<select class="director" name="genre" id="genre">
<option>-----------</option>
<option value="ActionMovies">Action Movies</option>
<option value="Horror Movies">Horror Movies</option>
<option value="Comedy">Comedy</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
Movie:&nbsp;<select id="movie" name="movie">
<option value="">-----Select----</option>
<option value="">Paranormal Activity</option>
<option value="">Johnny English</option>
<option value="">Avengers</option>
<option value="">Grave Encounters</option>
<option value="">Rio</option>
</select>
</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="CreateCookie();"></td></tr>
</table>
```

onclick i am calling this function..

here only one value is showing in alert.The second value is showing empty in alert.

Comment: You have given "<select id="movie" name="movie">" option values to be null.. give option values to that select option.

Answer (score 0):

You should not save those Informations in a normal cookie. A normal cookie might get lost if the user clear the browser-cache.

You better save those informations in a Database, identified by a session-cookie. Indirectly its been like a session-cookie who usually not get deleted if you delete the browser-cache. Also, if you identify a User from another browser, you have those customizations there too.